# Как проверить removeEventListenerr в тестах?

Tags: reactjs, юнит-тесты, enzyme

Как проверить removeEventListener в тестах?
Если вдруг удалят этот метод, то должна сработать ошибка.
Как проверить этот кусок кода?

```
 componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('message', this.setHeight);
}
```

Comment: Не надо дублировать вопросы.